# GWT, Enum, RadioButton and Editors framework

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

Here is the problem: I have a bean and this bean have a enum property:

```
enum E {
    ONE, TWO, THREE;
}

class A implements Serializable {
    public E foo;
}
```

I'd like to use [GWT Editor framework](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html) to let user edit this bean

```
public class P extends FlowPanel implements Editor<A> {
    // ... UiBinder code here ...
    @UiField RadioButton one, two, three;
    // ...
}
```

I've got an error:

> [ERROR] [gwtmodule] - Could not find a
>   getter for path one in proxy type
>   com.company.A
>
> [ERROR] [gwtmodule] - Could not find a
>   getter for path two in proxy type
>   com.company.A
>
> [ERROR] [gwtmodule] - Could not find a
>   getter for path three in proxy type
>   com.company.A

Is there a way to make this work in GWT 2.2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class EnumEditor extends FlowPanel implements LeafValueEditor<E> {

    private Map<RadioButton, E> map;

    @UiConstructor
    public EnumEditor(String groupName) {
        map = new HashMap<RadioButton, E>();
        for (E e: E.class.getEnumConstants()){
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(groupName, e.name());
            map.put(rb, e);
            super.add(rb);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(E value) {
        if (value==null)
            return;
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) super.getWidget(value.ordinal());
        rb.setValue(true);
    }

    @Override
    public E getValue() {
        for (Entry<RadioButton, E> e: map.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getKey().getValue())
                return e.getValue();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with the enum. The compiler is looking for the bean-like getter methods that correspond to the uiFields one, two and three. RadioButtons map to boolean properties as they implement the `IsEditor<LeafValueEditor<java.lang.Boolean>>` interface.

This should make your example code work, but it's obviously not a very flexible solution:

```
class A implements Serializable {
    public E foo;
    public Boolean getOne() {return foo==E.ONE;}
    public Boolean getTwo() {return foo==E.TWO;}
    public Boolean getThree() {return foo==E.THREE;}
}
```

To map a group of radiobuttons to a single enum property (and its corresponding getter/setter) you'd have to implement your own editor wrapping the radiobutton group, and returning a value of type E. It'd need to implement an interface like `IsEditor<LeafValueEditor<E>>`.

There's a [related discussion on the GWT group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/gxDLH21faF8/discussion)